# How to resolve AccessViolaton, when registered c# callback called in c++ thread

Tags: c#

I have a following C# code, and it works well.
It means a registered callback is called from C++ library as I expected.

But when I added a list and stored messages into this list for a while, 
I receieved following Error messages and
It looks application throws this error when list size exceeds some threshold.

And this error occurred when even a callback do nothing, but just Program class had a big string array.

```
class Program{

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void CallbackDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string message);

    [DllImport("ThirdPartyAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public extern static int Subscribe(CallbackDelegate callback] 

    int Main(string[] args){  

        :
        Subscribe(Callback); 
        Console.ReadLine();
        :
    }

    private static List<string> cache = new List<string>();
    private void Callback(string message){ 
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        cache.Add(message); // throw error when size exceedes threshold??
    }
}
```

```
Exception "Access Violation" (0xC000005) occurred at xxx memory at yyy can not be written

StackTrace:
xxx: C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll: RaiseException() +61 bytes
xxx: C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll: CreateApplicationContet() +<number> bytes
xxx: C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll: CreateApplicationContet() +<number> bytes
xxx: C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll: CreateApplicationContet() +<number> bytes
```

Could someone show me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you call the callback in parallel? Access to `List` has to be synchronized.

Comment: How is a string defined in the c++ code?  The c++ code should have a byte array terminated with a '\0'.  Most likely the c++ is missing the '\0'.  The marshal message continues to read the bytes until a zero is found.  If the zero is not found you will exceed the allowed memory array of the code and get the Access Violation.

Comment: To Haukinger: No, every time only one C++ thread adds the message into the list.

Comment: To jdweng: a string is defined as char*, and storing messages works for a few minutes. So I guess the message is end with '\0'